# Is it possible to capture the window.location.replace event?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, hashchange

If I'm currently at the URL`"example.com/somepage#somehash"` and I invoke `window.location.hash = "anotherhash"`, the URL changes to `"example.com/somepage#anotherhash"`. This fires the `window.hashashchange` event.

If I am currently at the URL `"example.com/somepage?a=1&b=two"` and I invoke `window.location.replace("?one=1&two=2")`, then the URL changes to `"example.com/somepage?one=1&two=2"`.

I've read the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange), and I can't find an even that this fires.

1. Is there one?
2. If not, is there a simple way to capture that event?

### Note:

It's my fault for saying that I want to make sure I don't trigger a page reload. I want to use the new URL for updating the page based on the query string, for example with an AJAX request. `window.history.pushState` is another option, but as far as I can tell, it does not fire an event either.

### Edit

I took a look at @Taki's answer. I create a [repl.it](https://repl.it/@abalter/windowlocationreplace-event) because you can see the URL change when you go to the full-page view. However, even with the `preventDefault` the page is reloading, which is proved by the fact that the info posted to the page in the unload event callback disappears. Consequently, this can't be used for client-side routing, which is my goal.

*index.html*

```
<button id="myBtn">Click me</button>
<div id="info"></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

*index.js*

```
console.log("index.js");

$('#myBtn').on('click', function(e)
{
  console.log("button clicked")
  window.location.replace("?one=1&two=2")
  console.log(window.location.href);
});

$(window).on("beforeunload", function (event) 
{
  event.preventDefault(); // just to pause and see the cosdole
  console.log("beforeunload");
  console.log(event);
  $('#info').append("<p>beforeunload</p>");
  console.log(window.location.href); // capture the url
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[window.location.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) acts like a redirection, so you can listen for the  [BeforeUnload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) event

> The **Location.replace()** method replaces the current resource with the
>   one at the provided URL

( don't know why it can't replace the `window.location` in the snippet :P but it'll work outside it )

```js
document.querySelector('#myBtn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  window.location.replace("?one=1&two=2")
});

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {

  console.log(window.location.href); // capture the url
  event.preventDefault(); // just to pause and see the condole
  
});
```

```html
<button id="myBtn">Click me</button>
```

**EDIT :**

apparently you can't prevent the page from reloading when changing `location.href` , but like you mentioned, you can use `history.pushState` and if it doesn't fire an event, create a custom one, attach it to the window and listen for it :

```
let evt = new CustomEvent('myEvent', ...
window.dispatchEvent(evt); 

... 

window.addEventListener('myEvent', function(e){ ...
```

this time it's working inside the snippet, see that it's not reloading and you get to keep urls in the history and you get your `location`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(elem){
  
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(e){
   
    e.preventDefault();
    window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", this.href);
    
    let evt = new CustomEvent('urlChange');
    window.dispatchEvent(evt);
    
  });
   
}); 

window.addEventListener('urlChange', function(e){
  document.querySelector('#myUrl').innerHTML = window.location.href;
});
```

```css
#myUrl{
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>hello</h1>
<a href="/one">Got to One</a><br />
<a href="/two">Got to Two</a><br />
<a href="?three=3">Got to Three</a><br />

<span id="myUrl"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks. I played with this, and I'm not sure it will work for me because it completely reloads the page anyway.

Comment: But that is my fault, because I did not say that I want to avoid a page reload. Changing the hash does not do that.

Comment: Use `pushState` and fire a custom `event` , check the edit

Comment: Yup. That would be the way to do it. Although it wouldn't be so much a custom event as another callback. So that I don't have to mess around, I'm just going to use a hash instead of "?" for the queries. Less traditional, but less code.

Comment: BTW--this really is a great example of a simple custom event. I will play with it some more.

Answer (score 1):

no there is not such event, the simplest way to detect when something like this is about to happen is to set a proxy around the history 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

or you can just override the methods for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
navigation.addEventListener('navigate, (e) => {
   console.log(e.destination.url)
})
```

P.S. for Chrome 102+